# How to open a WPF window from an external method call

Tags: wpf, com

I have a WPF application (.exe) which needs to open and display a window when a COM object (VB6 macro) calls an application method. I've made one managed code project in the .exe solution COM visible and the COM object successfully calls a method on the managed code project.

How do I start the WPF window from the managed code method? Do I need to make my entire exe COM visible? Do I need to turn my .exe into a class library .dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know the CLR is a COM server, so your managed method will be called in the same thread/process your COM object(the VB6 macro) lives.

Do you need to spawn your WPF app as a separate process(out of proc). This might be harder with the COM interop but if you want to go that way you can check that article [Building COM Servers in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/BuildCOMServersInDotNet.aspx?msg=3173538&display=Mobile).

Another, much easier option, is just to use Process.Start in your managed stub to execute your WPF app.

Comment: I added
    Process.Start("AwardManager.Presentation.exe");
in the managed stub. I get the following error from my VB6 macro that called my managed stub.

Comment: I added
    Process.Start("AwardManager.Presentation.exe");
in the managed stub. I get the following error from my VB6 macro that called my managed stub.
"Error running Macro 'myMacro' Automation Error"
This error is thrown when my Process.Start command is executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, the error went away when I added the full path to the file name. I know my process started, but my WPF window doesn't show.

Comment: You sure your process started? What is the 'invoking's application context? You may not have sufficient rights to start new processes.

Comment: OK, that all works after I swept a few bugs out of the way. As the great American poet, Paul Simon, says "Little by little, Bit by bit, Little bit by little bit.
Thanks